# Bucle FOR con saltos en PLSQL

Tags: oracle-11g, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

tengo que hacer un ejercicio que es un bucle for pero delimitando el minimo el maximo y el salto, la cosa es sque tanto el minimo como el maximo se hacerlo pero el salto no se como definirlo, espero que alguien me ayude.

Os dejo mi ejercicio sin el salto definido:

```
 SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CONTAR(var1 NUMBER)
 IS
 contador NUMBER;
 BEGIN
 contador:=0;
 FOR numero IN contador..var1
   LOOP
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Numero:' || contador);
   contador:=contador+1;
 END LOOP;
 END;

 SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
 BEGIN
 CONTAR(10);
 END;
```

Un saludo!

Answer (score 1):

Si por salto te refieres a que por ejemplo en vez de contarte normal siga algún patrón establecido (contar de 2 en 2, de 3 en 3, solo los pares, impares, etc) , simplemente integra un IF dentro del FOR con ese patrón. Por ejemplo, aquí solo te va a contar los números pares:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CONTAR(var1 NUMBER)
 IS
 contador NUMBER;
 BEGIN
 contador:=0;
 FOR numero IN contador..var1
 LOOP
   IF MOD(numero,2)=0 THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Numero:' || contador);
       contador:=contador+1;
   END IF
 END LOOP;
 END;

 SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
 BEGIN
 CONTAR(10);
 END;
```

Si necesitas mas detalles necesitaríamos que especifiques cual es el tipo de salto que necesitas.

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia okasio, si lo que necesitas es avanzar tu bucle en un orden diferente a i++, puedes usar un while, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
DECLARE
   c_loop BINARY_INTEGER;
BEGIN
   c_loop := a;
   LOOP
      EXIT WHEN c_loop > b;
      /*TU PROCESO*/
      c_loop := c_loop + c;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Donde a = Tu minimo, b = tu maximo, y c = tu salto.
Es decir si tienes a = 0, b = 10, c = 2. Entonces estaras realizando un bucle desde 0 hasta 10 de 2 en 2, y los valores de c_loop van a ser 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10.